# Pass array of observables to zip and read function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to put an array of observables to Observable.zip, but I don't know how to create a function for read values. Array is dynamically sized. Any ideas?

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/zip";


obsArray; 

functionName():Observable<any>{
  return Observable.zip(...obsArray, (arg1, arg2, arg3, ...) => {
       return { arg1: arg1, arg2: arg2, arg3: arg3, ...}
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I edited and posted code

Answer (score 1):

spread the array into the zip function and receive the response object.
You can run a `res.length` to get the length and use a for loop or run the foreach loop on it

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/zip";


obsArray; 

functionName():Observable<any>{
 return Observable.zip(...obsArray)
}
```

Comment: I need to doi it without subscribing - returned obesrvable will be pass to another Observable.zip

Comment: but how can create a return fuction for this zip?
This is my problem - Observable.zip(...obsArray, returnFunction)

Comment: provide a sample code in your question how you intend to use it, so that i can help from there.